# what is wrong with this program?the error comes 'cannot find symbol-variable Tom"

Tags: java, arrays, string

Wap to initialize 2 arrays,one with 5 names & another with their telephone nos.search for a name input by user.Print the name along with telephone no

```
   import java.io.*;
   class search {
    public static void main() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System. in );
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
        int i, j;
        String a[] = {Tom, chirag, mohan, pagal, debo};
        int t[] = {3442546, 5753432, 907879, 000, 3246};
        System.out.println("enter a name");
        String s = in .readLine();
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (a[i] == s) {
            System.out.println("Successful");
            System.out.println(t[i]);
        } else System.out.println("unSuccessful");
    }
   }
```

Comment: What is wrong? I'd start with the formatting.

Comment: You either need String instances with those names, or you need to put the values between quotes "Tom" to tell the compiler they are String literals.

Comment: the program is still not working.even if I type a name given in the array ,the output is :unsuccessful

Comment: Have a look at my answer's second paragraph: don't use `a[i] == s` but `a[i].equals(s)` instead. `==` will require the objects to be exactly the same instances which is not true in your case because you have a literal and a string instance created from input. The are equal but not exactly the same objects.

Answer (score 3):

String literals need double quotes around them.

For example `Tom` should be `"Tom"`.

Since you left out the quotes, the compiler is trying to interpret `Tom` as an identifier / symbol.  As you haven't declared `Tom` anywhere, it says "cannot find the symbol `Tom`".

Sometimes compiler messages can be a bit opaque. The trick to making sense of them is to try to understand what the compiler "thinks" you are trying to say ... not what you think you are trying to say.  (It can't read your mind.)

---

The other answers are correct about `==`.  It is very dangerous to use `==` to compare strings.  The compiler will happily except it, but the problem is that it *usually* gives the wrong answer.  Always use the `equals` method to test if two strings are equal.

---

Finally, once you have gotten past the basics of programming, you need to learn about Java style.  For example:

- Consistent indentation is very important.
- The correct capitalization for identifiers is very important:

  - A class name should always start with a capital letter; e.g. `search` should be `Search`.
  - A method or field name should never start with a capital letter.

I recommend you read / follow one of the following styles:

- Sun's original ["Code conventions for the Java language"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), or
- [Google Java Style](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html)

Comment: there is this last problem,even when the search is successful it prints successful & also unsuccessful a no of times.Say input:chirag and the output is:unSuccessful
Successful
5753432
unSuccessful
unSuccessful
unSuccessful

Comment: Surely you can work that one out for yourself.  Hint: this is >>your<< homework, and if you get someone else to solve all the "hard" problems for you, you won't learn.

Answer (score 3):

`String a[]={Tom,chirag,mohan,pagal,debo}` You're missing the double quotes here that denote a string literal in Java, i.e. `"Tom","chirag","mohan","pagal","debo"`

Btw, `a[i] == s` won't work since the literals are different objects from the strings created by the input. Use `a[i].equals(s)` instead.

As a sidenote, I'd probably use a `Map<String, Integer>` to map the names to the numbers and then instead of looping through the arrays you'd just do `map.get(s)` and check whether you get something or not. This would get rid of the risk that both arrays might differ in length and order.

Besides that I'd use `a.length` in the loop instead of the hard coded value 5, i.e. `for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)` or yet better `for (i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, t.length); i++)`.

Comment: there is this last problem,even when the search is successful it prints successful & also unsuccessful a no of times.Say input:chirag and the output is:unSuccessful Successful 5753432 unSuccessful unSuccessful unSuccessful

Comment: @DebalinaMazumder have a look at your code, you're looping through the array and print `unSuccessful` on every negative match. In your case `unSuccessful` reads like "no this element doesn't match, let's check the next". Either collect the values in the loop and check whether you got something afterwards or use the map approach I suggested to get rid of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 problems in your code

1. Initialization of String array should be

   `String a[] = {"Tom", "chirag", "mohan", "pagal", "debo"};`

ie string should be in double quotes.

2. Comparison of string is done with equals

   so change `if (a[i] == s)` to `if (a[i].equals(s))`

So the final code should be

```
InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System. in );
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
int i, j;
String a[] = {"Tom", "chirag", "mohan", "pagal", "debo"};
int t[] = {3442546, 5753432, 907879, 000, 3246};
System.out.println("enter a name");
String s = in.readLine();
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
if (a[i].equals(s)) {
    System.out.println("Successful");
    System.out.println(t[i]);
} else System.out.println("unSuccessful");
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/oKhlj0)